# In Avant Window Navigation (awn) can the icons jump?

Tags: awn

in avant window navigation (awn) can the icons jump? can the icons jump to call my attention if i receive a msg in messenger, or xchat, or if there a possibility to make them jump when i click on the icons?

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't that happen by default? I mean when I a program is updated (or a notification needs an attention) the icons should do a certain behavior depending on your settings.

Check the preferences & try different effects. The *jump* effect is called *classic*.

Comment: Jumping is the "classic" effect in the preferences.

Comment: @Javier You should make that an answer!

Comment: I believe that Saifallah answer is the correct one, mine is just an addition. If he doesn't add it to the answer in some time, I'll do. BTW, he's 58 on reputation and gives a good answer... I believe that it's better to add to his answer and try win a new member that made a new one.

Comment: @Javier Thanks mate I appreciate it, yours is more accurate so I wouldn't mind it as the "official" answer =)

Comment: i used awn and when i right clicked on the icons it crashed..so right now i using talika